# macOS Sierra (setFrameOrigin/setFrame) methods not setting NSButton frame

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-sierra

I'm simply trying to change my buttons position adjusting it a little to be properly placed in my app. So far in the previous versions (minimum 10.8) it has been working, but right in the latest mac release (10.12 sierra) it somehow does not change its frame or position..

sample:

```
 -(void)awakeFromNib
{
  [self.mybutton setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0,0)]; // not working...
  [self.mybutton setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]; // also not working...
}
```

Am I missing something? It should be as straight forward setting of frame.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm it was because I was using an older Xcode (version 7.3) to build the app that resulted the setFrameOrigin not to work, so I package a new app with the latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

I have a `NSImageView` in my `NSWindow`, and I need to move it around after the user presses on it (it is sort-of a calibration window). The `NSImageView` is created by Xcode 6.2 IB.

However, for other reasons, I **need** to compile my app with **that** older Xcode version (6.2, on Mavericks), so I *can't* update to Xcode 8 as suggested by the OP in the question comments. I didn't even try the OP's solution.

TL;DR: For me, it was an AutoLayout issue. It seems that macOS 10.12 Sierra has stricter AutoLayout rules than the ones on macOS 10.9-10.10-10.11 (where my app is being tested and supported). Go straight to Option 3 for the best solution.

## Option 1 (failing on macOS 10.9):

The first workaround is to simply remove the `NSView` from its superview, send `setFrameOrigin`, then re-add it to the superview:

```
NSView *supView = myView.superview;
[myView setFrameOrigin:NSZeroPoint];
[supView addSubview:myView];
```

This works pretty well in macOS 10.12 Sierra, however when testing on Mavericks `myView` is always stuck at position (0,0).

Then I realize that the `NSWindow` actually has AutoLayout enabled, and has some constraints set on *some other* `NSView`s (but NOT on `myView`): I'm using a mixed manual-Layout and Auto-Layout approach.

It turns out that **this** is the root cause of `setFrameOrigin` not working in my case.

## Option 2 (the quick way):

There's a magic knob that helps you when migrating from a traditional, non-AutoLayout approach to an AutoLayout one:

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

I set it in my `awakeFromNib` overload: all is working correctly in macOS Sierra now.

Unfortunately, testing on Mavericks shows some problems (again): although the behavior is correct (`setFrameOrigin` moves `myView` around), Xcode spits out many AutoLayout warnings on the console. However this seems one step in the right direction, and could be a definitive solution for someone else.

## Option 3 (THE solution):

Define some `NSLayoutConstraint`s on `myView` with IB, then use `removeConstraints` and `addConstraints` on the superview:

```
NSView *supView = myView.superview;
[supView removeConstraints:@[self.bottomConstraint, self.rightConstraint]];
[supView addConstraints:@[self.topConstraint, self.leftConstraint]];
[supView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
```

NOTE: `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded` is optional; you have to use it if you need to operate on `myView.frame` using the updated values (as in my case).

This code works correctly on macOS 10.9-10.10-10.11-10.12.